# Create class method with already existing name

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm working on some code working with MS Access database in VBA 6. My goal is to make this same code working with PostgreSQL too (this means it should be able to work with both) . The code is working with `DAO.DBEngine` but I've not found a way to make this class connect to a PostgreSQL database. My solution is to create an other class with the same methods as `DAO.DBEngine`, for example the original code is using TableDefs and when I'm create a function called TableDefs I got "ambiguous name detected". Is there any way to name two methods class the same or to suppress/avoid this "ambiguous name detected" error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information provided in the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bO50gHRndA) you could create three classes

*IDatabase*

```
Option Explicit

Function Hello()
End Function
```

*clsDBAccess*

```
Option Explicit

Implements IDatabase
Function IDatabase_Hello()
    MsgBox TypeName(Me)
End Function
```

*clsPostSQL*

```
Implements IDatabase
Function IDatabase_Hello()
    MsgBox TypeName(Me)
End Function
```

And you could use it like that

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    
    Dim myType As String
    Dim oDatbase As IDatabase
    
    ' Determine myType
    myType = "Access"
    ' myType = "PostSQL"
    
    Set oDatbase = ClassFactory(myType)
    
    ' Your code here
    oDatbase.Hello
    
    
End Sub


Function ClassFactory(dbType As String) As IDatabase

Dim oDatabase As IDatabase

    If dbType = "Access" Then
        Set oDatabase = New clsDBAccess
    ElseIf dbType = "PostSQL" Then
        Set oDatabase = New clsPostSQL
    End If
    
    Set ClassFactory = oDatabase
    
End Function
```

Comment: What if one of those classes (clsDBAccess or clsPostSQL) is loaded from a DLL ?

Comment: That seems to be a new question. Please create a new post and clarify what you are doing excatly. It sounds that you just need to wrap it but without details it's difficult to tell.