# Create class method with already existing name from a DLL

Tags: vba, ms-access

I come from this post : [Create class method with already existing name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67088965/create-class-method-with-already-existing-name), where I explain that I need to make code compatible with MS Access and PostgreSQL. My first thought was to create a new class for PostgreSQL support and rewrite the functions previously used. The solution brought could work, but the problem is that the MS Access database class is loaded from a DLL (`Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll`, `DAO.DBEngine`). How can I interface or override those DLL functions and get rid of this "ambiguous name detected" error ?

Comment: You can create an interface for a dll if you wrap the dll in a VBA class.  The VBA Class methods merely act as a passthrough to the dll object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67090654/6600940) to your first post you can use the Implements feature to do this. Without further details and yout code it is just more than difficulut to tell where your issue is.

*IDatabase* could look like that

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenDB(fileName As String)
End Sub

Function ReadData(lngNr As Long) As String
End Function
```

*clsAccess* like that

```
Option Explicit

Implements IDatabase

Dim m_Dbs As DAO.Database
Dim m_Rcd As DAO.Recordset
Dim m_Filename As String

Sub IDatabase_OpenDB(fileName As String)
    m_Filename = fileName
    Set m_Filename = OpenDatabase(m_Filename, , True)
End Sub

Function IDatabase_ReadData(lngNr As Long) As String
    Set m_Rcd = m_dbs.OpenRecordset("qryTable", dbOpenSnapshot)
    m_Rcd.Move lngNr - 1
    IDatabase_ReadData = m_Rcd.Fields("fldName").Value
    m_Rcd.Close
End Function
```

You need to add the references in Tools/References.